# Invert dictionary with lists in different lengths in python 3.X

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code (inspired by code in other thread):

```
def inverter(a):
    b = {}
    for k,v in a.items():
        for i in v:
            b.setdefault(i,[]).append(k)
    return b

x={'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':'grape'}
print(inverter(x))
```

the problem is that it returns this output:

```
{'apple': ['orange'], 'peach': ['orange'], 'g': ['cherry'], 'r': ['cherry'], 'a': ['cherry'], 'p': ['cherry'], 'e': ['cherry']}
```

It seems to iterate over each letter of last value, instead of iterating once.
How do I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that orange maps to a list of values but cherry does not. You should fix this type mixture instead of hacking around it.

Comment: Try with `x={'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':['grape']}` as input..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that sometimes your values are lists that should be iterated and sometimes your values are strings that should be kept together, yet are iterable.

Consider the following:

```
def pairs_from_dict(d): 
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            yield (v, k)
        else:
            yield from ((k_i, k) for k_i in v)
```

The generator above assumes dict-values are either strings or should be iterated, but you can add additional checks to your heart's content.

It is also assumed that all the values from which you want to generate keys are unique, e.g. no `{'cherry': 'grape', 'banana':'grape'}` in the original dictionary because dictionary keys must be unique.

It works like this:

```
>>> d = {'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':'grape'}
>>> dict(pairs_from_dict(d))
{'apple': 'orange', 'grape': 'cherry', 'peach': 'orange'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem. If there are more elegant solutions out there, will appreciate:

```
def inverter(a):
b = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    if type(v) is list:
        for i in v:
            b.setdefault(i,[]).append(k)
    else:
        b.setdefault(v,[]).append(k)

return b

x={'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':'grape'}
print(inverter(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment by MisterMiyagi is the reason for your problem. By iterating through `v` where `v='grape'`, you are getting each individual letter, because you are iterating through a string. To fix that, you could check instance-type:

```
def inverter(a):

    b = {}
    for k,v in a.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                b.setdefault(i,[]).append(k)
        else:
            b.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
    return b
x={'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':'grape'}
print(inverter(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some of your dictionary values are lists, others are strings. Strings are iterable, just like lists, and therefore you see letters used as keys.

You can use a ternary statement for the conditional logic. Also, more efficient would be to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def inverter(a):
    b = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in a.items():
        for i in v if isinstance(v, list) else [v]:
            b[i].append(k)
    return b

x = {'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':'grape'}

print(inverter(x))

defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'apple': ['orange'], 'peach': ['orange'], 'grape': ['cherry']})
```

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote already, the problem is that sometimes your values are lists and sometimes your values are strings which act as iterable itself.
One possible solution:

```
def inverter(a):
    b = []
    for k,v in a.items():
        if isinstance(v,list):
            b.extend([[x,k] for x in v])
        else: 
            b.append([v,k])
    return dict(b)

x={'orange':['apple','peach'], 'cherry':'grape'}
print(inverter(x))
```

**Out:**

```
{'apple': 'orange', 'peach': 'orange', 'grape': 'cherry'}
```